# Use of unresolved identifier "GMSAutocompleteFilter"

Tags: swift, google-maps, swift3

I added GoogleService-Info.plist, created bridging header with

```
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
```

and

```
GMSServices.provideAPIKey(Keys.google)
```

works, but compiler cannot find "GMSAutocompleteFilter", which is included in "GoogleMaps.h" according to [Google Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete?hl=ru). Another classes are defined just fine:

[image]

I used the function from the google tutorial to test:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer: it wasn't stated in the Google Document, but I should have added

`pod 'GooglePlaces'`

to my podfile and

```
#import <GooglePlaces/GooglePlaces.h>
```

to the bridging header.

Comment: I don't know which version of cocoapod you use but i don't need the bridging just `import GooglePlaces`